# How many transactions are required on trust before I can withdraw money?

Tags: transactions, trust-wallet

I am using Trust to purchase bitcoin.  I wanted to withdraw funds.  I was told I needed another five transactions before I could withdraw funds?  Is this a policy that so many transactions are required before you a withdraw funds?  If this is the policy does a certain amount of money needed to be spent on buying bitcoin to qualify for the five transactions in order to withdraw funds?

Comment: P.s. you are being scammed by criminals. Don't send them any more money. Report theft to your local police.

Comment: Hi Dawn, I've never heard of “Trust”. So, I'm not sure whether you're asking about the rules of your customer relationship with some Bitcoin brokerage, or whether as RedGrittyBrick suspects you're being misled by some scammer. Perhaps you could tell us a little more about what you're trying to do and who your business partner is. Please also check out the link that RedGrittyBrick provided.